# VBA - How do I create an Excel sheet with the same name without a (2) at the end of the name of the Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 weeks.  I create in VBA a sheet with the name "TestSheet Monday". Now I create again a sheet with the "TestSheet Monday". But when I do this a sheet is created with the name "sheet (2)".

*My question here is, how can I create a sheet which then adds a number or other naming to the end of the sheet name. For example => "TestSheet  Monday" and "TestSheet  Monday second", instead of "TestSheet  Monday" and "sheet (2)".*

Here is the code with which I create an Excel sheet.

```
    testSheetName = GetTestSheetName(targetAmount)

    'Unprotect sheets
    UnProtectSheet "Test"
    UnProtectSheet testSheetName
    
    'Create Test Sheet
    Sheets("TestSheet").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = testSheetName
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B7").value = WeekDay
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating sheet with same name again and again which is not possible. Change this line `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = testSheetName` to

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = testSheetName & "_" Sheets.Count
```

Here `Sheets.Count` will add total sheet number after sheet name. You can add anything here as you desire like `testSheetName & " Second"`.

Comment: This  _could_ create the same problem if sheets are deleted.

Comment: Then OP needs to use different things rather than `Sheets.Count`.

Comment: @Harun24HR Do you have an idea of what I can try to solve this problem?

Comment: @SavanCvijetic Do you have chance to delete sheets?

Comment: @Harun24HR Yeah, but I have to have the same default value to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using this?
Sheets.Add.Name = "TestSheet Monday"

Comment: This will create same problem when OP will create sheet again. Sheet name must be different than exiting sheets.